# Which is the best Angular 4 architecture?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, architecture

I am writing a "social network" app with Angular 4 (typescript) and Angularfire and I have this problem:

Now I have a single app.routing module that makes possible to navigate through 5 main pages (example home, settings, profile and so on). I would like to implement inside each page multiple "dashboard like" components.
I want that each component to have the possibility to route inside the self component.
For example

App.component -route-> home.component

home component will has 2 components inside called with  and

Inside comp1 I would like to be able to change the content of it with a button and route inside of it maintaining the other home components the same:

Is it possible?

Searching on the web I found some examples with named outlet or component with a custom module declared.

Has somebody some GitHub source or examples?
Or, I'd like to have some suggestions for the best architecture app.

Thanks

Comment: you are looking for child routes i guess

Comment: In this moment I am using child routes but if I have two components inside Home (that is a child too) it seems to be able to manage only one component (indeed I notice this problem only today that I added one another component)

Comment: there is something wrong in you setting up the routes it should be able to distinguish both , hope you are not using any wild card and routes are ordered properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Angular's guide for lazy-loaded modules. Lazy loaded modules have their own routing: 
https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router
But if you don't want to use lazy loading, child routes may be enough for you: 
https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration